# R merge() by column names in one data frame, and a column in the other

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to use the merge function in R. I have a list of column names (Stock names) in some data frame D. I then have another data frame 'Info' where these Stock names are stored in a column, with a corresponding sector name in the next column. I need to merge these sector names to a row in D.

If I were merging on 2 columns, I could use merge() directly and alter by.x and by.y and the emrged values would appear as extra columns. However, D has the name I am merging by as its column names, so I essentially want it to add on extra rows? The following code didn't work:

```
M<-merge(D,Info[,c("Name","Sector")],by.x=colnames(D), by.y=c("Name"))
```

P.S I have searched around on SO, but nobody has precisely this problem. They have similar ones, but those approaches are not valid for this.

Comment: Add a small reproducible example which depicts your issue.

Comment: Why the vote down? At least tell one, so one can correct it in the future.

Comment: I am not sure why there is a down vote on this. Check this link [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, `D` looks like

```
set.seed(1)
D <- data.frame(matrix(runif(9), nc=3))
names(D) <- sample(LETTERS, 3)

> D
          B         F         E
1 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753
2 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978
3 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.6291140
```

Where in this example, `B`, `F`, and `E` are stock names.  Presumably `info` looks like this:

```
info <- data.frame(NAME=LETTERS, sector=letters)
> info
   NAME sector
1     A      a
2     B      b
3     C      c
4     D      d
5     E      e
6     F      f
7     G      g
..snip..
```

The idea is to extract the right `sector` from `info`, then `rbind` that vector to `D`. Note that `rbind` matches the names of the first and second objects.

```
merged <- rbind(D, sapply(names(D), function(x) info$sector[info$NAME==x]))
> merged
          B         F         E
1 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753
2 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978
3 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.6291140
4 2.0000000 6.0000000 5.0000000
```

`sector` (which was a factor type) has been converted to a float.  To make the merged table look nice, you could do

```
rbind(format(D),
  as.character(
    sapply(names(D), function(x) info$sector[info$NAME==x])
  )
)
          B         F         E
1 0.2655087 0.9082078 0.9446753
2 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.6607978
3 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.6291140
4         b         f         e
```

But now your numbers are really characters, which may or may not be useful for you.